# Sqoop Import using Hue - using inner query

Tags: sqoop, hue

I am trying to sqoop data in to hive table from mysql db in apache cloudera .

Below is the sqoop query that i am executing:
sqoop import  --connect  jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test --username admin --password admin --incremental append --check-column sale_id --last-value 0  --query 'SELECT s.sale_id,c.cust_id,c.state,s.qty FROM   customer c JOIN sales s on c.cust_id = s.cust_id WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by s.sale_id --hive-import --hive-table sales --target-dir /user/cloudera/sales_products --hive-delims-replacement '/t'

Query works fine when I execute it from command prompt/console. However when I am trying to execute same by HUE UI job designer I am getting below error:
Error parsing arguments for import

I think it is because of $CONDITIONS argument.

Can you please let me know if it is possible to execute the same query using Hue and how it is feasible.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hue will submit this script through Oozie [Sqoop Action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html). It has a particular way to specify the arguments.

Hue also comes with a built in Sqoop example that you could try to modify with your import.

Answer (score 0):

The **Where $CONDITIONS** is required when running sqoop statements through Hue, at least I have not been successful without it.

I use [the method I describe in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732986/listing-ms-sql-server-table-in-oozie-via-sqoop-action/45471382#45471382) to load data from SQL Server into External Hive tables, tables that sit in an HDFS folder.  Here is the DDL I use to create the table from Impala but it can also be used from the Hive editor.

```
CREATE TABLE HiveDB_NameSpace.ExternalHiveTableName (
    ColumnName1 STRING
    ColumnName2 STRING,
    ColumnName3 STRING,
    ColumnName4 STRING,
    ColumnName5 TIMESTAMP,
    ColumnName6 INT
    ColumnName7 STRING
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION '/user/foldername/dbname/tablename';
```

This works very well for landing 100+ tables.  I can then clean, refine, and conform the data as I insert it into internal Hive, Kudu or other tables.